# Migration error(Migration is applied before its dependency accounts.0001_initial on database 'default')

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, deployment

I'm trying to migrate my custom user model and I run makemigrations command to make migrations for new models. But when I run migrate command it throws this error :

> raise InconsistentMigrationHistory(
> django.db.migrations.exceptions.InconsistentMigrationHistory:
> Migration admin.0001_initial is applied before its dependency
> accounts.0001_initial on database 'default'.

Trace back:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\enosh\venv_ruling\ruling\manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\enosh\venv_ruling\ruling\manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\enosh\venv_ruling\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 419, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\enosh\venv_ruling\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 413, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Users\enosh\venv_ruling\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 354, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\Users\enosh\venv_ruling\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 398, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Users\enosh\venv_ruling\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 89, in wrapped
    res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\enosh\venv_ruling\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\migrate.py", line 95, in handle
    executor.loader.check_consistent_history(connection)
  File "C:\Users\enosh\venv_ruling\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\loader.py", line 306, in check_consistent_history
```

**models.py**

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser


class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    """extend usermodel"""

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'CustomUser'
```

I just mentioned user model in this question but still if more code is required then tell me I'll update my question with that information. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Delete the DB
2. Delete pycache and migrations from all the apps
3. Make sure you have set AUTH_USER_MODEL
4. Make migrations

Comment: Not working. Just getting the same error message. First, you have to makemigrations for the user, then makemigrations for everything else.

Answer (score 0):

I just thought I might throw in my experience with this - as a Postgres noob.

Using Postgres with the OPTIONS clause in settings.py

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
...
        'OPTIONS': {
            'options': '-c search_path=main,dev'
....
        },
```

It was not immediately apparent to me that Postgres searches for the table in *those schema in order*.

So if you are wanting to do a clean, first, initial migration into the 'main' schema - be sure there was no previous migration made in schema 'dev'.

Current current migration in 'main' will fail because it finds mis-matched migration data in 'dev'

Answer (score 0):

Fake migrations on a project can sometimes be troubleshot using --fake

```
python manage.py migrate --fake
```

Answer (score 0):

1. delete `db.sqlite3(database)`
2. open accounts > migrations folder and delete `0001_initial.py`
3. open your terminal and apply `python manage.py makemigrations`, then
   `python manage.py migrate`

Comment: Isn't this what the accepted answer already says? Please don't repeat answers.